# How to Link two apps in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want to link two flutter ios apps. For that I want if one login, other automatically login and on one logout other automatically logs out,

Anyone who can suggest me how to start?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You will have to use an online database that connects with both apps and syncs user data.

Comment: okay, thanks Abbas! I will figure out further on it.